# Possible Bug: Why does ListLinePlot3D not work with Dynamic here?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, warning-messages, interactive

Why are the errors below thrown? They are very strange and seem to be incorrect.

### Error 1

```
ListLinePlot3D[Map[Dynamic, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {2}]]
```

[image: 1]

### Error 2

```
ListLinePlot3D[Dynamic[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}]]
```

[image: 2]

- All three of the following throw no errors and give the correct output.

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}]

Dynamic[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}] 

Dynamic[ListLinePlot3D[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}]]
```

Notice the last two include `Dynamic` applied to a literal, and they work fine with no errors.

So the problem seems to be with `ListLinePlot3D[Dynamic[...],...]`.

### Update

I understand a Dynamic on a literal will not do anything. The code here are minimal examples whittled down from more complex and pragmatic code, and *the same errors are given when `Dynamic` is applied to a non-literal*. I chose literals to make the minimal examples simplest. The code shown should work, even if `Dynamic` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Dynamic on a literal will not do anything because a literal cannot change its value.

Comment: I’m trying to figure out why these errors are thrown. It doesn’t seem like these errors make sense. The practical function I am using is more complex than this, but I reduced the problem to this. My overall code is of the form ListLinePlot3D[Dynamic[…]].

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan - I don't know if that would work in general, why not `Dynamic[ListLinePlot3D[...]]`?

Comment: All of the Plot functions do a lot of funky stuff. They need to hold evaluation of the function part to some extent, but they also do a ton of other stuff to set up the visualization. I personally don't know exactly why your case is throwing an error, but it doesn't surprise me at all that it does.

Comment: On another topic, nested Dynamics and superfluous Dynamics sometimes end up doing weird things (or at least things that seem weird to me). If you really need a Dynamic, I suggest you put it as far to the "outside" of the expression as possible, ideally the outermost wrapper. Except, of course, in the cases of controls that are specifically designed to take Dynamic expressions as arguments.

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan The linked topic is not about plots but I think it identifies the culprit here. Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: The trouble in this particular case is that `ListLinePlot3D[data]` tries to rewrite data into `Point` and `Line` objects, stripping wrappers from the data like `Tooltip` and rewrapping them around the `Point` and `Line` objects as appropriate. Unfortunately, it is not programmed to do that with `Dynamic`. Basically if it dealt with `ListLinePlot3D[Dynamic@data]`, then whenever `data` changed, the whole `ListLinePlot3D[]` would have to re-execute, and it would effectively behave just like `Dynamic@ListLinePlot3D[data]`. Maybe that's why they didn't implement `ListLinePlot3D[Dynamic@data]`.

Comment: @lericr That seems to be the solution, but its a bit unfortunate though because performance seems to be better with inner `Dynamic`s, in my very limited experience.