# Making Tooltips Work with Buttons in 3D Plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic, button, tooltip

I am trying to get buttons to work simultaneously with tooltips in 3D plots. `Button` has a `Tooltip` option, but it doesn't seem to work.

Consider code that creates a red point that turns green when clicked, and the point works with a tooltip.

In the following, `Button` works , but its `Tooltip` option does not.

```
DynamicModule[{b = 1}, Graphics[
  
  Dynamic@Button[Style[Point[{0, 0}],
     {Red, Green}[[Mod[b, 2, 1]]],
     PointSize[0.1]], b++, Tooltip -> "hi"],
  
  ImageSize -> Small]]
```

[image: 1]

Thankfully, we can add the `Tooltip` function to make it work. Both `Tooltip[Button[` and `Button[Tooltip[` work. For example...

```
DynamicModule[{b = 1}, Graphics[
  
  Dynamic@Tooltip[Button[Style[Point[{0, 0}],
      {Red, Green}[[Mod[b, 2, 1]]],
      PointSize[0.1]], b++], "hi"],
  
  ImageSize -> Small]]
```

[image: 2]

However, *all three fail in some 3D plots*.

We can see the button works, but its `Tooltip` option still fails.

```
DynamicModule[{b = 1},
 Dynamic@ListLinePlot3D[
   
   {{2.1, 
     Button[Style[2.9, {Red, Green}[[Mod[b, 2, 1]]]], b++, 
      Tooltip -> "hi"], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2}},
   
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.05}]]
```

[image: 3]

With `Tooltip[Button[`, `Tooltip` works but `Button` does not.

```
DynamicModule[{b = 1}, Dynamic@ListLinePlot3D[
   
   {{2.1, 
     Tooltip[Button[Style[2.9, {Red, Green}[[Mod[b, 2, 1]]]], b++]], 
     2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2}},
   
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.05}]]
```

[image: 4]

With `Button[Tooltip[`, `Button` works but `Tooltip` does not.

[image: 5]

How can I get such a button to work with a tooltip in `ListLinePlot3D`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may do it (it does what I think you might want):

```
DynamicModule[{b = 1}, 
  ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, 
     Button[Style[2.9, {Red, Green}[[Mod[b, 2, 1]]] // Dynamic], b++, 
      Tooltip -> "hi"], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2}}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.05}]] /. 
 c : Button[p_, r___] :> 
  Button[Tooltip[p, Tooltip /. Options[c] /. Tooltip :> Sequence[]], 
   r]
```

Might be a bug, I suppose.

Alternative:

```
DynamicModule[{b = 1},
 Dynamic[
  ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1,
      Button[Style[2.9, {Red, Green}[[Mod[b, 2, 1]]]], b++, 
       Tooltip -> "hi"], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2}}, 
    PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.05}] /. 
   c : Button[p_, r___] :> 
    Button[Tooltip[p, Tooltip /. Options[c] /. Tooltip :> Sequence[]],
      r]
  ]]
```

Comment: This is great, but unfortunately, due to the problem discussed in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/266773/12697, my code only works with `Dynamic` in front of `ListLinePlot3D`.

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan See update.

Comment: I do wonder if you are aware of the gift you are to the world. Thank you!